# Is there a way to cleanup database tests in Rails 6.0.3.1 System Tests. I thought Rails does the cleanup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automated-tests

Using

- Ruby `"2.7.1"`
- Rails `"6.0.3.1"`
- Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5
- Using the default Rails Minitest and FactoryBot for test data.

**Issue:** I have test data being shared between system test files and hence failing tests. When I run the system test files individually the tests pass but this is inconvenient.

I use the the system test config out of the box as in the `application_system_test_case.rb`

**This is my system test scenario.**
I have 3 `Customers` in `customers_system_test.rb` file and 1 `Customer` (so far) in `job_description_system_test.rb` Customer 1 appears in the `customers_system_test.rb` failing test screenshots that Rails conveniently provide.

Note: The 3 failing tests all concern record counts such as `assert_equal Customer.count, 3`

**The 3 failing tests**

```
test "visit create customer and navigate back" do
  ...
  assert_equal Customer.count, 3
end
```

```
test "cancel destroying a customer" do
  assert_equal Customer.count, 3
  ...  
end
```

```
test "destroy a customer" do
  assert_equal Customer.count, 3
  ...
end
```

Interestingly I had the same issue with test data not being cleaned up when running `rails test` for controller, integration tests etc: The way I get around that is adding the following snippet to the `test_helper.rb` :

`(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - %w{schema_migrations}).each do |table_name|`
  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name} CASCADE;"`
`end` Doesn't work for system tests

I feel like I am missing the obvious?

`test_helper.rb`

```
require "simplecov"
SimpleCov.start "rails"

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  # parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)
  parallelize(workers: 1)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  # fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
end

(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - %w{schema_migrations}).each do |table_name| 
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name} CASCADE;"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got all tests running and passing including system tests by doing the following (wasn't aware this was necessary in Rails 6)

```
...

setup do
    sign_in user
    @customer_1 = FactoryBot.create(:customer_with_job_descriptions)
    @job_description_2 = FactoryBot.create(:job_description, customer_id: @customer_1.id)
  end

  teardown do
    @customer_1.destroy!
    @job_description_2.destroy!
  end

...
```

Ref: 8 Setup and Teardown
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html#setup-and-teardown

```
........................................................................................

Finished in 22.971069s, 4.3968 runs/s, 21.4182 assertions/s.
101 runs, 492 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: You absolutely should not do this in Rails. Rails guarantees your database will be reset to empty between tests, you don't have to implement this yourself.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that Rails guarantees that databases are reset to empty between tests but this is not the case in the app I am working on. If I don't do the setup and teardown methods I have test data being shared between tests.

Comment: @meagar should I untick the answer I added?